# OpenCart variables in home.tpl

Tags: php, opencart

So i'm trying to display the categories on the homepage in a custom theme of OpenCart.

In the header.tpl you can use variables as `$categories` and so fort, but when I want to use these variables in the home.tpl file, it says it doesn't exists.

Is there any way to make these variables working in the home.tpl file? I can't find any line in the header.tpl that includes a PHP files where all these variables can be found.

Comment: Variables are usually passed to template function, so you need to find a part of the code where this happens

Comment: Do you know where I can find this? The header.tpl can be found here: https://shrib.com/NrCB6c8S

Comment: Bondye has an answer. I've just explaied to you how this stuff work, so in future it will be easier for you.

Comment: I think first you should get yourself familiar with the MVC pattern...

Comment: To get yourself familiar with the file locations and MVC - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484904/711273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the controller of header.tpl called [header.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/header.php) In there, you can find the part where `categories` is assigned ([line 93 to 124](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/header.php#L93-L124))

Paste this part into the [home.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/home.php) ([on line 18](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/home.php#L18))

Now the variable `categories` is available.

Comment: Good, that's clear to me.
But my home.php looks very different from the home.php from the github page.
Mine can be found here: https://shrib.com/QFbz8goq
So where do I need to paste this code now?

Comment: I guess just before `setOutput`. I would paste it after `$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');`

Comment: I pasted it right there but when I now get the page, I get a white page with no errors at all.
This is my home.php right now: https://shrib.com/Ro3NReqs

Answer (score 2):

(1) search in `common/header.php @ class ControllerCommonHeader` for the code fragment that constructs categories array, in my project (v 1.5.5.1) I have it like that

```html
$this->data['categories'] = array();

$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

foreach ($categories as $category) {

...
```

(2)
Copy that code snippet to `common/home.php @ class ControllerCommonHome @ function index()`, now you can use it in `home.tpl`

Comment: Well, it's better to use something that's set rather than setting new variable.

Comment: @VeeeneX but we can't use **$categories** in **home.tpl** directly as it is not defined in **home.tpl controller**, so I think that I should copy the code, right?

Comment: I mean that is what the question is about ? may be I understood your comment in a wrong way

Comment: When you are using templates, it always have a function where it's parsing variables into template so when you find this point as Bondye done you can simply add this variable to that function and variable will be accessible in template. That's first method another is your's but it can took more execution time.